# Convert Pandas Timestamp with Time-Offset Column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utc, timezone-offset

I get daily reports which include a timestamp column and a UTC Offset column. Using pandas, I can convert the int Timestamp into a datetime64 type. I unfortunately can't figure out how to use the offset.

Since the 'UTC Offset' column comes in as a string I have tried converting it to an int to help, but can't figure out how to use it. I tried using pd.offsets.Hour, but that can't use the column of offsets.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8', delimiter=r'\t',engine='python')
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df[r'Stream Timestamp'],utc=True, unit='s')
print(df[:3][r'Stream Timestamp'])

0   2019-05-01 14:21:37+00:00
1   2019-05-01 15:50:12+00:00
Name: Stream Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]

0    -06:00
1    +01:00
2    -04:00
Name: UTC Offset, dtype: object

df[r"UTC Offset"] = df[r"UTC Offset"].astype(int)
```

Optimally, I want to do something like this

```
df[r'Adjusted'] = df[r'Timestamp'] + pd.offsets.Hour(df[r'UTC Offset'])
```

However I can't seem to figure out how best to reference the column of offsets. I'm a little new to datetime in general, but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the prettiest, but since when you read in the csv it is an object you can shave off the old offset and combine it with the offset column as a string. For this to work all of the Timestamps when read in must have the offset. If they don't consider maybe checking if there is a + or - in the string and then going from there.

Then convert to datetime. I included the `format` parameter in the `pd.to_datetime` just so it would be faster, however you do not need this if your dataset is small. I am actually surprised at how hard it is to get information for pandas timezones, but maybe check out tzinfo?

I included the intermediate steps in different columns for ease of understanding, but you of course need not do this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp_str': ['2019-05-01 14:21:37+00:00', 
                                     '2019-05-01 15:50:12+00:00', 
                                     '2019-05-01 15:50:12+00:00'],
                   'utc_offset': ['-06:00','+01:00','-04:00']})

df['timestamp_str_combine'] = df['timestamp_str'].str[:-6] + df['utc_offset']
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_str_combine'], 
                                 format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", utc=True)

df.info()
```

Output

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
timestamp_str            3 non-null object
utc_offset               3 non-null object
timestamp_str_combine    3 non-null object
timestamp                3 non-null datetime64[ns, UTC]
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1), object(3)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to convert to datetime as it's easier to apply offsets than with native pandas time format.

To get the timezone offset:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone # pip install tzlocal

millis = 1288483950000
ts = millis * 1e-3
local_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, get_localzone())
utc_offset = local_dt.utcoffset()
hours_offset = utc_offset / timedelta(hours=1)
```

Then apply the offset:

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],infer_datetime_format=True,errors='ignore')
df['dtos'] = df['dt'] + timedelta(hours=hours_offset)
```